# Overriding ToString() on MEF MetadataAttribute

Tags: c#, generics, mef

I have a MEF MetadataAttribute:

```
[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage]
public class MyTestAttribute : ExportAttribute, IMyTest
{
    public MyTestAttribute(string pluginInfo)
    {
        _pluginInfo = pluginInfo;
    }

    string _pluginInfo;
    public string PluginInfo{get{return _pluginInfo;}}

    public override string ToString()
    {
         return PluginInfo;
    }
}

public interface IMyTest
{
    string PluginInfo{get;}
}
```

I have some other metadata attributes which inherits from other interfaces. All my attributes overrides `ToString()`. I am using the method below to get plugins:

```
            public void GetPlugins<TSender, TEventArgs, TAttributeMetadata>()
            {
                var importedPlugins = _container.GetExports<Action<TSender, TEventArgs>, TAttributeMetadata>(contract);
                foreach(var plugin in importedPlugins)
                {
                      string pluginInfo = plugin.Metadata.ToString();//this here is not
                      //returning plugin info. It is returning some kind of Guid and the interface name
                      //I could retrieve the pluginInfo via reflection but I don't want.
                }
            }
```

My question is why `ToString()` is not returning the pluginInfo? What should I do to get pluginInfo? is it possible without reflection or dynamics?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: As a hint (limited time right now), I have seen metadata used for everything from informational text to filtering imports in MEF, and I have never seen the `ToString` method be involved in the process.

Comment: @280Z28 I am sorry. My English is not very good. I am not understanding what you saying. Could you please explain? Thanks

Comment: Why even use ToString()? why not just access `PluginInfo` on the metadata object?

Comment: @aL3891 I was going to override the ToString() method in my AttributeClass to return some information about plugin. Also I am using generics in this case. To get all the properties I had to use reflection (which I don't want to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the exported metadata is a view and not an instance of your metadata class. It is a class, implementing your metadata interface (`IMyTest`), that is automatically generated by MEF. So, it doesn't have the `ToString` implementation of `MyTestAttribute`.

Comment: I guess this can't be solved without reflection or typecasting.